# How to protect Windows Server 2008 r2 from persons, which have physical access to computer?

Tags: windows, security, group-policy, password

One server is available for other users, and we think that someone may steal passwords from it. I can not set a password on boot, because sometimes there is electricity failure, and UPS can hold it only some time, after such reboot system must be loaded automatically, without user interaction, so truecrypt or bios password is not an option.
I know that there are some rainbow tables, ntlmhash crack apps,
but i would like to reduce risk as much as possible.
What are best practices to secure windows computer?
(Physical isolation, locks, are not an option here)

Comment: There is no reliable, fool-proof way to secure a computer running any OS unless you can guarantee the physical security of the computer. Best practices for securing a server begin and end with controlling physical access. You might as well ask what the best practices are for not getting mauled to death by a bear after you've already kicked it hard in the groin then stuck your head between its jaws after smothering yourself in honey.

Comment: Do bears REALLY like honey? always wondered...

Comment: @DarkcatStudios http://www.adfg.alaska.gov/index.cfm?adfg=wildlifenews.view_article&articles_id=371

Comment: @RobM - Well, you learn something every day :-D

Answer (score 4):

The ONLY option you have is to stop people being able to access it: you need to find a way to either stop physical access (IE put it in a locked cabinet, move it to a locked office etc) or make console access impossible (disable all HID access, disable all USB/PS2 ports etc)

Answer (score 0):

The way I would do it is create a fullscreen .exe in Visual Studio, and change the post-Winlogon shell path from `explorer.exe` to your new .exe, under `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon -> Shell`

And for any functions that explorer is responsible for, I would then start `explorer.exe` silently inside your program.

Disabling `Ctrl+Alt+Del` and `WinFlag-M`  will also be necessary. [This article](http://www.northcode.com/blog.php/2007/07/25/Securing-Windows-For-Use-As-A-Kiosk) has an interesting way of doing it.